# Where are value-type function arguments stored in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, storage, memory, calldata, data-types

When we define a function, say `test(uint256 val)`. I would presume `val` would be implicitly defined in memory. But what if we change the funtion visibility modifier, does that change the location of where `val` is defined?

I'm interested in 3 function visibility modifiers, `public`, `internal`, and `external` and their effect on the location where `val` would exist. I'm also interested in whether it would make a difference if we access the function internally or externally, given that the function visibility modifier is set. Does it make a difference if, say the function is defined as `external` and we try to access it internally from the same contract code vs if we access it externally from another contract or from an EOA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments passed to external and public functions are passed to the contract via calldata, if called from outside the contract (a transaction).
They are not directly modifiable; (they are copied in memory if needed).

The function visibility does not change the storage position

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=storage#storage-memory-and-the-stack

> [...], the called contract (which can be the same as the caller) will receive a freshly cleared instance of memory and has access to **the call payload - which will be provided in a separate area called the calldata**.[...]

to check this you can create a simple contract with a function in remix like

```
    function asd(uint256 value) public pure returns(uint256) {
        value = value +100;
        return value;
    }
```

and by debugging the transaction you can see in the left-side memory panel that the value is copied to memory

---

unless specified by **storage** keyword, variables created inside functions are created in memory and are obviously not persistent between different transactions.

--
if, for example a contract function defines a new variable and then calls another function passing that variable as an argument, it will be read from memory, because it is where it was created originally.